# Login by personal SSL certificate using Django and nginx

Tags: django, authentication, ssl, nginx, openssl

How can I implement user authentication using personal SSLs
(as signin at startssl.com).

After registration user download his certificate, and login without login/pass.

I would appreciate any help?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a package like [django-ssl-client-auth](https://github.com/kimvais/django-ssl-client-auth). That will do what you need I believe.